# Understanding assembler instruction

Tags: assembly, inline

I was looking into below answer at

### [LPC1768 / ARM Cortex-M3 microsecond delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480939/lpc1768-arm-cortex-m3-microsecond-delay)

```
#define CAL_FACTOR ( 100 )

void delay (uint32_t interval)
{
  uint32_t iterations = interval / CAL_FACTOR;

  for(int i=0; i<iterations; ++i)
  {
    __asm__ volatile // gcc-ish syntax, don't know what compiler is used
    (
      "nop\n\t"
      "nop\n\t"
      :::
    );
  }
}
```

---

What is \n\t after nop? I looked into GCC Assembler guide but could not find answer.

Comment: This might help = https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer at 
http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/rmiyagi-inline-asm.txt

'\n\t' at the  end of each line except the last, and
    that each  line is  enclosed in quotes.   This is because  gcc sends
    each as instruction to as  as a string.  The newline/tab combination
    is required so that the lines are fed to as according to the correct
    format  (recall that  each line  in assembler  is indented  one tab
    stop, generally 8 characters).

Comment: The tab is not required, though.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly block seems to be read as plain text and instructions are separated with line breaks, if you write

```
"nop\n\tnop\n\t"
```

it should work as well.